# No software solution to turn off the screen other than Assistive Touch?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ipados

The physical power button is hard to press. Isn't there any other way to turn off the screen, without using external hardware like a cover and not using Assistive Touch?

1. Turn off button in the Control Centre: Android allows third-party apps to add custom actions to the quick settings. Is something like that not allowed in iOS? That is, there is no way to add a turn off button in the Control Centre?
2. Turn off using the physical home button: It seems long press is for Siri, but I do not use Siri. Can't I assign long press to turn off the screen? How about double click to turn off the screen? It seems that I could set an action for a triple click, but turning off the screen was not available.
3. Any app to turn off the screen?: On Android, there is an API to lock the screen or turn off the screen without locking (on newer Android versions), so there are apps that add widgets to turn off the screen. There is no such API on iOS, so a third-party app solution is not possible at all?
4. Any inbuilt gesture to turn off the screen? I don't know, something like 5-finger tap or 5-finger swipe down, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assistive touch is the way to do this.

It is the only way, because it's the feature that was designed to meet this need.

You can toggle assistive touch with the triple click, if you want an easy way to hide/show the menu.

Comment: This sucks. Assistive Touch shows a big circle on the screen that is always there. I looked into settings and it allowed the user to customer the left/right corner swipe, but the only two actions I could choose was screenshot and memo. Why can't there be more, like turning off the screen? I don't understand Apple's decisions.

Comment: @DamnVegetables did you set "Idle Opacity" for Assistive touch?